# Disable mouse side button Alt-Tab behavior in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech M720 mouse. It has a button hidden in the grip part below the common Back and Forward buttons. The button has become quite easy to press, which opens the same dialog as Alt-Tab on Windows 10 and allows me to switch between windows.

This behavior is now very annoying as gripping the mouse a bit harder opens the dialog when I don't want to switch windows.

How do I disable this behavior? There are many screenshots of the Windows Mouse Properties showing the exact settings I need on the Buttons tab, but it seems to be specific to IntelliPoint and I don't see those settings on my system.

Note: I would like to avoid installing any crapware from Logitech as it's a work computer.

Comment: You'll need the crapware, either Logitech's or some 3rd party.

Answer (score 3):

A Bluetooth device may send commands to windows without the OS knowing the physical properties of the device. So there's no way such behaviour could be controlled through the OS. Only the behaviour of the standard mouse buttons (left, right, wheel) can be controlled directly through the OS: these are the only buttons which are common across all manufaturers.

Personally, I am using the "Logitech Options" software, which is availabel also for your M270. I would not at all call it a crapware, but an essential piece of software to get the most out of your mouse. It is lightweight and has practically no system impact. It will allow you to tune your mouse exactly to your needs. In many situations, exact mouse tuning can considerably speed up your workflow.

Here's a screenshot of typical system impact:
[image]

Consider "Logitech Options" more like a manufacturer-specific DRIVER for your device, which happens to have a user interface. Like with any hardware, if you don't install the specific driver, not all functions of your hardware will be available.
The difference with an IntelliPoint mouse is that the IntelliPoint driver is tied differently to the OS and can be opened through the System settings. You can't do that with Logitech Options. But at the end of the day, the impact on your system will be similar, since every driver always will have a (minnimal) impact on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue.  I am using Logi Options+ software for the M720 mouse.  In games, rather than the lower thumb button applying the Keystroke assigned to it within Logi Options+, it behaves like Alt-Tab.

Update - for my issue, i rebooted my PC and it worked again.  Somehow the mouse had disconnected from the Unifying received / Logi software and reverted to the basic connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).